# How to start evolution in a specific folder?

Tags: 11.10, unity, evolution

having a problem with Evolution (3.2.2).
When Evolution starts, it opens the last folder I've used.
How can I set that it should open alwaays the inbox after start?
Couldn't find any settings.
Thanx in advance.

W.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_evoluti.htm) says that you can provide the folder to start with as a command line parameter. So you will have to edit the shortcut you use to start Evolution to point to your folder.

Comment: Thanx, good page/answer, but doesn't work here.